# TypeError: a.geometry.getBounds is not a function in OpenLayers.js (line 611, col 334)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openlayers-2

I'm using OpenLayers 2.13 and Postgresql 9.3 for my development activities.
I want to load region data from database and load into openlayers.

Below result i'm getting from St_astext(geom) in postgresql 9.0 and above

> "MULTIPOLYGON(((77.6620335903023 12.8381894855534,77.6620330917475
>   12.8384550503658,77.662583464913 12.8384554346975,77.6625831247336 12.8381894684868,77.66234257162 12.8381895285991,77.6622741102056 12.8381895459662,77.6620335903023 12.8381894855534)))"

But in postgresql 9.3 i'm getting the below result with height parameter while using St_astext(geom)

> "MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((77.6620335903023 12.8381894855534 0 0,77.6620330917475 12.8384550503658 0 0,77.662583464913 12.8384554346975 0 0,77.6625831247336 12.8381894684868 0 0,77.66234257162 12.8381895285991 0 0,77.6622741102056 12.8381895459662 0 0,77.662033590 (...)"

Below is the OpenLayers code to featch the wkt format

> var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new
>   OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT("MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((77.6620330345526
>   12.8382017120463 0 0,77.6620403164933 12.8384556061155 0 0,77.6625840206627 12.8384543231982 0 0,77.6625747884884
>   12.8381889127371 0 0,77.6620330345526 12.8382017120463 0 0)))"), null,{
>
> label : "TEST",
>   irregular: true,
>   cursor:'pointer',
>   fontSize: "14px",
>   fontFamily: "arial, monospace",
>   fontWeight: "bolder",
>   labelAlign: "cm",
>   fillColor: "#9fdaef",
>   fillOpacity: 0.3,
>   strokeWidth:4,
>   strokeColor: "#005596"
>   });

I'm getting an error like below

> TypeError: a.geometry.getBounds is not a function in OpenLayers.js
>   (line 611, col 334)

By using Multipolygon without height parameter i can able to load region data in Openlayers

but, with the height parameter i can't.

Please guide me to load wkt value with height parameter in Openlayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ST_Force2D

```
ST_AsText(ST_Force2D(your_geometry_column))
from your_table;
```

Just try this to see the effect:

```
SELECT g,
      ST_AsText(ST_Force2D(g::geometry)),
      ST_AsEWKT(ST_Force2D(g::geometry))
      FROM ( SELECT
'MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((77.6620335903023 12.8381894855534 0 0,77.6620330917475 12.8384550503658 0 0,77.662583464913 12.8384554346975 0 0,77.6625831247336 12.8381894684868 0 0,77.66234257162 12.8381895285991 0 0,77.6622741102056 12.8381895459662 0 0,77.6620335903023 12.8381894855534 0 0)))'
::text as g ) as foo;
```

If you use this WKT you should be fine:

[image]